# How to make an API call to a local ruby file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby

I know how to make API calls in angular using the $http service, but all of the examples online call a web API. My issue is that a coworker of mine built an API using ruby, and I don't know how to call it since it is in my local environment.  Here is the Ruby Code:

```
class Api::SignageAgentController < ApiController

   def index
      render json: Ingestor.signage_agents.to_json
   end

   def update
      return render(status: :unprocessable_entity,json: ['No signage agent given']) unless @ingestor == Ingestor.signage_agents.find_by_id(params[:id])

      if @ingestor.update_attributes(valid_params)
         render json: @ingestor.to_json
      else
         render(status: :unprocessable_entity,json: @ingestor.errors.to_a)
      end
   end

   protected

   def valid_params
      params.require(:signage_agent).permit(:policy_file_keys) rescue {}
   end
end
```

How would I go about calling the index in angularjs?

Comment: Angular runs on the client (web browser); Ruby runs on the server (different computer, different location). You need Angular to make an XHR request to the server, and the Ruby code on the server can then call other Ruby code on the server. In this case you may want to instantiate a new `Api::SignageAgentController` either during the request, or app startup, and call methods on it.

Comment: Can you show us you're `config/routes.rb`, but only the ones related to `signage_agent`?

Comment: @fbelanger 
It seems as if the reference to the signage agent is missing something, the other api's called in the routes file have "do" with some other code beneath them.  Here it is:

`resources :signage_agent, only: [:index, :update]`

Comment: Hey ADHDTurtle, first of all good luck with all your endeavours. What you are doing is insanely challenging and painful. Work hard and it will pay off. Second, this line indicates that we need to `GET` the index at `/signage_agent`. However, without more details about the namespaces the URL path will vary. Please provide the nested routes starting after `Rails.application.routes.draw do` and everything that wraps around the `resources :signage_agent, only: [:index, :update`]. The controller is dubbed `Api::`, which traditionally implies some kind of API path setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would depend on the URL path defined for this `Api::SignageAgentController`.

If you have access to the project, go to the `config/routes.rb` and look for something like `signage_agent`.

Assuming that your routes are something like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, { .. } do
    # get '/signage_agent', to: 'signage_agent#index'
    resources :signage_agent, only [:index, ...]
  end
end
```

Then, in Angular:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/api/signage_agent'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {

  }, function errorCallback(response) {

});
```

Depending on the `{...}` part, your URL path could vary.

If you don't see `subdomain` or `path`, then everything is fine.

If these are present, then you might need a Rack Proxy like `pow` or `prax`, if you're on Linux.

Test your endpoints (URL paths) using your browser or better yet use Restful API Testing plugins for your browser or freely available online solutions (Google: rest api test online)

Try reading up on Rails Routing, as this will help you utilize AJAX on the Front-end. Learning about Rails Routing will also help you understand how to consume your company's API.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing.html

You'll find that the combinations in the `config/routes.rb` is all you really need to understand.

Restful APIs use HTTP verbs (get, post, put/patch, delete) to map controllers, notably their actions (which handles a web request), to URL paths.

You're `index` action is likely to be setup to a `GET` request with just the controller name, no `/1`, which represents an ID (thus `params[:id]`).